# how to achieve this washed out processing effect

Tags: post-processing

[image: unsplash photo]

this photo from unsplash has an interesting effect. it's hazy and washed out and has this cinematic effect. I have not seen the original but i am guessing it would be a lot more clear.

how could this be achieved in photoshop or lightroom?

Comment: I suspect that is the original! The Golden Gate is notorious for low fog.

Comment: An alternative would be to buy a package of Presets for LR like VSCO, which I would imagine could have very well been used for this image.

Comment: @David, it might be possible in camera, but is unlikely to be the result with default settings, since the blackpoint is quite high (the darkest colors are actually only mid-dark gray).

Comment: @mattdm, a quick search produced the following image (http://www.sanfranciscotim.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/13-Golden-Gate-Bridge-In-Fog-1024x768.jpg) which seems to be similar to the image in this question.

Comment: @mattdm, here's a second image of the Golden Gate Bridge in fog (http://fc09.deviantart.net/fs71/i/2011/319/e/1/golden_gate_bridge_in_the_fog_by_falcorn0squirrel-d4gat6n.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite easy in Lightroom. The first thing I would do is start with an image of a bridge in some fog, the good news is that I have one already. Too bad it isn't the Golden Gate and too bad it's not that great of a shot :)

[image: The Duluth Liftbridge in Fog]

Then head over to the develop module in LR and the Tone Curve selection. Inside of it click on the bottom right box to "Edit Point Curve":

[image]

Add a point in near the bottom left of the linear curve:

[image]

Add a point at the far left of the linear curve and drag it up a bit until you achieve an appropriate amount of fading:

[image]

The result after I also increased the Vibrance and Grain as well:

[image: Final edited image]

Comment: Perfect. Now I don't have to finish my answer. :)

Comment: If you have an alternative method please do. I don't have any fancy histogram like you.

Comment: No it was pretty much literally the same, except in Gimp instead of Lightroom. :) Feel free to borrow the histogram.

Comment: there are some good videos on adobe further explaining tone curve in LR along with differences from photoshop https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom/how-to/lightroom-adjust-tone-curve.html

Answer (score 0):

If this image is digital, you can achieve similar effect if you layer black and white version of the image over the color one and play with layer interaction methods (overlay, multiply, etc.), transparency of the B&W layer and with the B&W layer tonality (levels, midtone contrast, B&W conversion etc.).

Look up Bleach Bypass method for both digital and darkroom technique with similar effect.